# WPFアプリケーションにおいて、UserControlのコードビハインド内で、親側で設定したx:Nameを取得したい。

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, xaml

XAMLのWindowにユーザーコントロール(UserControl1)を2つ配置しました。
それぞれのx:Nameに"UC1", "UC2"を指定しております。

```
<Window xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 x:Name="UC1" Height="100"/>
        <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 x:Name="UC2" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

UserControl1のコードビハインドのコンストラクタにて、
"UC1"または"UC2"を取得することは可能でしょうか？

コードビハインドで、
this.Name
と記述することで取得可能かと考えましたが、正しく取得できませんでした（UserControl1のXAMLで指定した、x:Nameが取得されます）。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainWindow`のコンストラクターで`InitializeComponent`が完了するまではMainWindow.xamlの内容は反映されません。なので`UserControl`側だけで処理したいのであれば`Loaded`イベントなどをハンドルする必要があります。

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;
    }

    private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
        Loaded -= UserControl1_Loaded; // 複数回発生するので終わったら解除する
    }
}
```